# Remove continuous occurrence of vowels together in a string using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have a string like below:

```
"i'm just returning from work. *oeee* all and we can go into some detail *oo*. what is it that happened as far as you're aware *aouu*"
```

with some junk characters like above (highlighted with '*' marks). All I could observe was that junk characters come as bunch of vowels knit together. Now, I need to remove any word that has space before and after and has only vowels in it (like oeee, aouu, etc...) and length of 2 or more. How do I achieve this in python?

Currently, I built a tuple to include replacement words like `((" oeee "," "),(" aouu "," "))` and sending it through a for loop with replace. But if the word is 'oeeee', I need a add a new item into the tuple. There must be a better way.

P.S: there will be no '*' in the actual text. I just put it here to highlight.

Comment: Try: `(?<=\s)[aeiouAEIOU]{2,}(?=\s)`

Comment: tried text.replace("(?<=\s)[aeiouAEIOU]{2,}(?=\s)"," "), but no changes to the string done.

Comment: what happens if you use `re.sub()`?

Comment: here is what I get: "i'm just returning from work.   all and we can go into some detail oo. what is it that happened as far as you're aware aouu". The first junk character is removed.

Comment: You will need to replace the `\s` with `\b` in the regex that anubhava suggested. It should work fine then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=re%20m#re.sub) to do a regex replacement in python. You should use this regex:

```
\b[aeiou]{2,}\b
```

which will match a sequence of 2 or more vowels in a word by themselves. We use `\b` to match the boundaries of the word so it will match at the beginning and end of the string (in your string, `aouu`) as well as words adjacent to punctuation (in your string, `oo`). If your text may include uppercase vowels too, use the [`re.I`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=re%20m#re.I) flag to ignore case:

```py
import re

text = "i'm just returning from work. oeee all and we can go into some detail oo. what is it that happened as far as you're aware aouu"
print(re.sub(r'\b[aeiou]{2,}\b', '', text, 0, re.I))
```

Output

```
i'm just returning from work.  all and we can go into some detail . what is it that happened as far as you're aware
```

Comment: Even better @JvdV

Comment: Why not just `\b[aeiou]{2,}\b` ?

Comment: @JvdV thanks - a moment of mental aberration there. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @anubhava you are also correct, I've updated the answer.